how to share a image in click to chat in WhatsApp?
I was trying to share image of bill to the customer in my app, i have their contact also i can sent the text in WhatsApp, now i want to share the image of receipt to the customer contact ,is there is way ??
thanks in advance!!
            try {
                    PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
                    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                    Bitmap bitmap = captureDialogContent(dialog); // Capture only content
                    Uri uri = saveBitmapToCache(bitmap);


                    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
                    i.setType("image/*");

                    String url = "https://api.whatsapp.com/send?phone=" + phone + "&file=" + uri;
                    i.setPackage("com.whatsapp.w4b");
                    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                    if (i.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
                        context.startActivity(i);
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


could you please add error or exception as well
